# LINQ DataContext Concurrency Between 2 Applications

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I have a database that is accessed by two applications. The first is an ASP.NET MVC application which just reads data out of the database. The second is a C# Console application which reads and writes to the database.

The problem I'm experiencing is that when the console application performs a mass update of up to several hundred rows, the MVC application will crash and burn. If I purge the entire database and refill it, the MVC application comes back to life, but anytime the console application needs to perform an update the MVC app will crash.

What I assume is happening is that the DataContext in the MVC application sees that the data has changed and doesn't know what to do. Or at least that's what I think is happening because the exception being thrown, System.Web.HttpUnhandledException, is really vague and is being caught by the OnException Controller override.

I have tried several fixes, but none of which did anything:

1. Restarting IIS or the entire server does not help.
2. Overriding the OnActionExecuting in the Controller and telling it to create a new DataContext does not work.
3. Overriding the OnActionExecuting in the Controller and telling it to refresh the DataContext does not work. (Although I'm not 100% sure this failed because I did this:)

   DataContext.Refresh(System.Data.Linq.RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues, this);

The compiler let it go through so I assumed it understood what I was trying to do...

4. (4) Wrapping each ActionResult with a using statement and creating a new DataContext doesn't work.

I would appreciate any suggestions anyone might have on how I should  fix this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the inner exception on the System.Web.HttpUnhandledException?

Comment: Sorry for delay, had to modify my exception handling and "break" the application to get the InnerException. The InnerException is "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.", also quite vague...

Comment: @thekaido, after a bit more digging, I found the problem. The console app whiped out all images, and the MVC app was trying to display them... Anyway, its now a console app issue and not a DataContext issue. If there's one thing I learned from all this and you is to look at the inner exceptions as well... If you post an answer I'll give your points. THANKS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the inner exception.  If the inner exception is null, make sure you are doing a "throw" not a "throw ex" so that the stack trace doesn't get reset.